# XmlDocument Load Error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, iis-6

```
string configFilePath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PATH"].ToString();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlTextReader reader = null;
reader = new XmlTextReader(configFilePath);
doc.Load(reader);
reader.Close();
```

doc.Load(reader) gives the following error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Edit: 
The path is http://localhost/something/mydoc.xml and in the filesystem the IIS user has access, also I tried with an "everyone full control" but nothing changed.
I tried to put the path into the url box of IExplorer and it shows the xml correctly.

Comment: What is the value of "PATH" in your config file?  Sounds like it's to a remote HTTP or HTTPS URI that you don't have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and after some research, came up with a solution
(see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15269061/1042643)).

In this case, setting the XMLURLResolver solved my issue

```
XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
resolver.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;                    

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
reader.XmlResolver = resolver;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value of "PATH" is trying to connect with any type of remote machine it sounds like it doesn't have access.  So, if your "PATH" value is something like "\ComputerName\SharedDirectory\file.xml" be sure the user has permission to the "ComputerName" machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the XmlResolver?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.xmlresolver.aspx#Y883